# SQL - Many to Many alternatives?

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

Suppose I have records:

```
======= =========
Element id
======= =========
        "H"
        "O"
```

And another like:

```
======== ==
Compound id
======== ==
         "Water"
```

With:

```
======== == =========== ========== ==========
Relation id compound_id element_id bond
======== == =========== ========== ==========
         1  "Water"     "H"        "Covalent"
         2  "Water"     "H"        "Covalent"
         3  "Water"     "O"        "Covalent"
```

Now,  *most* of my queries aren't for an exact match, but suppose *sometimes* I want to find the compound with the exact elements = `["H", "H", "O"]` (i.e. *Water* -- but not *Hydroxide* (`["H", "O"]`) or *Peroxide* (`["H", "H", "O", "O"]`).

**How might I go about this?**

- [Consensus seems to have it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17371639/how-to-store-arrays-in-mysql), that the best way to store arrays in SQL is through many-to-many intermediate tables.
- However, [querying for an exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19036165/sql-query-for-exact-match-in-many-to-many-relation) without arrays seems slow and complex, even with database-specific functions like `GROUP_CONCAT`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always better to keep your database normalized. In your particular case, I would store the number of elements per compound instead of having a new row for each element.

```
 compound_id element_id      bond         count
 -------------------------------------------------
   "Water"     "H"        "Covalent"        2
   "Water"     "O"        "Covalent"        1
```

The query for the exact match will be

```
 select compound_id
 from elements
 group by compound_id
 having count(
              case when 
                (element_id = 'H' and count = 2) or
                (element_id = 'O' and count = 1) then 1 
              end
        ) = count(*)
```

However, this approach will be suboptimal, since a sequential scan will be used. If denormalization is not a problem, storing a number of different elements per compound can help.

```
 compound_id   element_count
 ------------------------------
   "Water"          2
```

Then the query may be

```
 select e.compound_id
 from elements e
 join compounds c on e.compound_id = c.compound_id
 where c.element_count = 2 and
       ((e.element_id = 'H' and e.count = 2) or
        (e.element_id = 'O' and e.count = 1))
 group by e.compound_id
 having count(*) = 2
```

and if you have an index on `compounds(element_count)` and `elements(element_id, count)` then your query will use it to retrieve the results fast even if the database is large.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use `array_agg()`?

```
select compound_id
from t3
group by compound_id
having array_agg(element_id order by element_id) = array['H', 'H', 'O']
```

Comment: I'll consider this if I switch to Postgres, but for now `array_agg` is the Postgres-only equivalent of Mysql's `group_concat` that I mention in the question.